# How to get the whole scene rotate around itself? (my code has a little bug which just lets the objects rotate around themselves)

Tags: c++, opengl

What must be changed to let me see the impression of flying around the whole fixed scene? My current code just lets me look from a fixed viewpoint at objects each one rotating around itself. Enabling glLoadIdentity() just stops their rotation. Note that 3dWidget::paintGL() is permanently called by a timer every 20ms.

```
void 3dWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glRotatef(3.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);

    glPushMatrix();
    //glLoadIdentity();

    for (int i = 0; i < m_cubes.count(); i++) {
        m_cubes[i]->render();
    }

    glPopMatrix();
}

void Cube::render() {
    glTranslatef(m_x, m_y, m_z); // local position of this object
    glCallList(m_cubeId); // render code is in createRenderCode()
    glTranslatef(-m_x, -m_y, -m_z);
}

void Cube::createRenderCode(int cubeId) {
    m_cubeId = cubeId;

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, m_pCubePoints);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, m_pCubeColors);

    glNewList(m_cubeId, GL_COMPILE);
    {
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, m_numPoints);
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    }
    glEndList();
}

void 3dWidget::init(int w, int h)
{
    ...

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    float aspect = w/(float)(h ? h : 1);
    glFrustum(-aspect, aspect, -1, 1, 10, 100);
    glTranslatef(0., 0., -12);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

---

EDIT: It seems it's important to know that 2 cubes are created with the following 3D position coordinates (m_x, m_y, m_z):

```
void 3dWidget::createScene()
{
    Cube* pCube = new Cube;
    pCube->create(0.5 /*size*/, -0.5 /*m_x*/, -0.5 /*m_y*/, -0.5 /*m_z*/);
    pCube = new Cube;
    pCube->create(0.5 /*size*/, +0.5 /*m_x*/, +0.5 /*m_y*/, +0.5 /*m_z*/);
}
```

Comment: you don't move the camera you move the world around the camera ;)

Comment: @ratchetfreak: yes, I know that this must be done, technically. I described the effects from the impression I have while watching it.

Comment: @falkb: I think my SO answer on the OpenGL transformation pipeline will be of great value to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13223392/524368

Comment: can you recognize in my code why the cubes rotate each one around itself, and what I should do to get the effect of looking at a scene rotating around its centre? What must be changed in the C++ code above? your link is very interesting but does not explain how I can fix my problem.

Comment: Side note: You should integrate an angle of rotation (this->angle += 3 in paintGL) and apply `glIdentity(); glTranslatef(…); glRotatef(angle,…); glTranslatef(…)`. This avoids creeping rounding errors due to an ever-lengthening chain of matrix multiplications. It also obviates `gl(Push|Pop)Matrix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I've found the reason by myself. It works as soon as I change method `paintGL()` to

```
void 3dWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

#if 0 // not working
    glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glRotatef(3.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
#else // this works properly, they rotate horizontally around (0,0,0)
    glRotatef(3.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
#endif

    for (int i = 0; i < m_cubes.count(); i++) {
        m_cubes[i]->render();
    }
}
```

I don't get it exactly why, but it obviously appeared that some transformations had compensated in a way that the objects just rotate around itself. Thanks for your help anyway.

I think it's always better to let the scene rotate than to move by gluLookAt (beside the issue that finding the right formula for the angle of view is more difficult).

Comment: You've just changed the point that the scene rotates around. I assumed that the two translations were there intentionally to rotate the scene around the point [0.5 0.5 0.5]. Was this not intended?

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Probably it wasn't clear enough but "scene rotate around itself" means around (0,0,0). The translate-rotate-translate code was just copied from another example.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gluLookAt](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) to position the camera. You apply it to the modelview matrix before any object transforms.

Obviously, you'll have to figure out a path for the camera to follow. That's up you and how you want the "flight" to proceed.

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, there's no camera concept, as such, in OpenGL. gluLookAt is just another transform that (when applied to the modelview matrix) has the effect of placing a camera at the prescribed location.

If you really are just trying to rotate the world, your code seems to perform the transforms in a reasonable order. I can't see why your objects rotate around themselves rather than as a group. It might help to present a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) using glut.

Comment: My code tries a fixed camera and just wants to rotate the whole scene to get the fly-effect. I've heard it's better than to move the camera.

Comment: @falkb: Actually there is no camera in OpenGL. gluLookAt just moves around the scene if used at the right place in the transformation chain.

Comment: @datenwolf: Thanks for pointing out the possible confusion. I've added a clarifying paragraph.

Comment: please, also read my own answer given parallel to this answer